# permutation of separate rows of matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix, vectorization

How to effectively vectorize the following MATLAB code, which performs permutation of each row of matrix R by indices in corresponding row of matrix P?

```
for i = 1:size(P,1)
   pP(i,:) = R(i,P(i,:));
end
```

example:

```
P = [3     2     1;
     3     1     2;
     2     3     1;
     2     1     3;
     1     2     3;
     1     3     2]

R = [6     5     4;
     6     4     5;
     5     6     4;
     5     4     6;
     4     5     6;
     4     6     5]
```

produce following matrix pR:

```
     4     5     6
     5     6     4
     6     4     5
     4     5     6
     4     5     6
     4     5     6
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One approach with [`bsxfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) -

```
nrows = size(R,1)
pP = R(bsxfun(@plus,[1:nrows]',(P-1)*nrows))
```

Or with [`ndgrid`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ndgrid.html) -

```
[m,n] = size(R)
pP = R(sub2ind([m n],ndgrid(1:m,1:n),P))
```

Or replace `ndgrid(1:m,1:n)` with [`repmat`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/repmat.html): `repmat([1:m]',[1 n])` or with [`meshgrid`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/meshgrid.html):`meshgrid(1:m,1:n).'`.

Comment: I prefer the second method.

Comment: @GameOfThrows Thanks! I would go with `bsxfun` for efficiency! :)

Comment: I too prefer `bsxfun` approach ;)

Comment: bsxfun solution is perfect ... efficiency is my most important target!

Answer (score 0):

This might not be the best way to do it, but you could do something like:

```
IND1 = P(:,1)
Q(:,1) = diag(R(:,IND));
```

and repeat for P(:,2), P(:,3) in a similar fashion.

Comment: this is not vectorization ... ?!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `arrayfun` to avoid the loop but probably won't gain in performance if that it is the reason for vectorizing it:

```
cell2mat(arrayfun(@(k) R(k, P(k,:)), (1:size(P,1)).', 'uni', 0))
```